# What is the best way to let an app widget communicate with a service

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast, android-appwidget

I want my AppWidget (homescreen widget) to communicate with a `Service`, when the user presses a `Button` on it. That `Service` needs to be permanently running as long as the appWidget lives. As far as I know the only way to react on a widget's `onClick` event is to send `PendingIntents` via broadcasts. Currently I'm receiving these at my `MainActivity`, which forwards it to the running `Service`.

So actually I'm using my `MainActivity` as some kind of proxy for my widget's incoming events. Is this the right way? I would prefer to communicate with my `Service` directly - is this possible?

Comment: then let me rephrase this: I want that app widget always to play a sound, when it is being clicked. If a service isn't always reachable, means running, the widget could fail to play the sound, would't it? I don't want to use a `IntentService`, since it would be killed after every playback and then recreated on the next one.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with starting an IntentService every time?  If I installed your app and found that it had a permanent service running, I'd leave a bad review and then uninstall it.

Comment: disposing and initializing of a new `MediaPlayer` intance just to play a sound seems to be extremely recource-hungry

Comment: You should try reading the documentation on [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).  It tells you to release it when you're not using it because it can consume a lot of resources.  Just use an IntentService and recreate it every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That Service needs to be permanently running as long as the appWidget lives

This is an anti-pattern in Android. It's also effectively impossible as a result. If you want reliable results and users not attacking you with task killers, redesign your app to not require an everlasting service.

> As far as I know the only way to react on a widget's onClick event is to send PendingIntents via broadcasts.

There are three factory methods on `PendingIntent`: `getActivity()`, `getService()`, and `getBroadcast()`, to have the `PendingIntent` perform `startActivity()`, `startService()`, and `sendBroadcast()`, respectively.

> I would prefer to communicate with my Service directly - is this possible?

Use a `getService()` `PendingIntent` instead of a `getActivity()` or `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`.